# How to change the background of the button widget in PGU v0.21?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pgu

How can I use my own images as the background for the button widgets in **PGU v0.21** library, specifically for the `hover` and `pressed` states. I have tried setting the `style.background` attribute for the normal state and it's worked, but I don't know how to set my custom image to the `hover` and `pressed` states of the button widget. Can someone please provide guidance or example code on how to accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```py
import pygame
from pgu import gui

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 640))
caption = pygame.display.set_caption('Button Test')

app = gui.App()
container = gui.Container(width=100, height=100)
btn = gui.Button("Click me!", width=287, height=60)
btn.style.background = pygame.image.load("assets/images/gui/button_normal.png")
container.add(btn, 0, 0)
app.init(widget=container)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        app.event(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    window.fill((20, 20, 20))
    app.paint(window)
    pygame.display.update()
```